# Powerbuilder Icon issue

Tags: windows, icons, powerbuilder, taskbar

I'm running into an issue where after building an application with Powerbuilder, some users have no issue with viewing icons within the application while others can't see the icons. Also, the main icon for the application doesn't display on the Windows Task bar. I'm going to play with the icon size but if anyone else has any recommendations, that would be great!

Comment: Is the icon included in the compiled resources, or is it used directly from filesystem? If the latter and the application is deployed on a fileserver, that problem might occur.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like to re-compile the executable every time there's a small graphic change or a customization that applies to only one library, and I don't like to compile graphics into the executable... it makes the exe file very large.  No reason to rebuild the exe unless the library list changes.  So I use .pbr files, and just rebuild the pbl with a pbr file.

My graphics.pbr file resides in the same directory as my graphics so I don't have to mess with environment variables or worry about file paths.  I created an empty graphics.pbl in the AppCore directory, and a graphics.pbr in the graphics directory. The graphics.pbl is in the application's library list.  When I have to add or edit graphics, I simply rebuild the graphics.pbl with the graphics.pbr.

I have multiple customers using the same application, with their own graphics (logos) so I do the same thing there.  Here's what my directory structure looks like:

MyApp

MyApp.pbw

AppCore

```
graphics.pbl

bunch more libraries
```

AppGraphics

```
single resource file, graphics.pbr

bunch of icons and graphics
```

Customer1

```
Customer1.pbl

Customer1.pbr

a few libraries for customization and container for application object

a few custom graphics
```

Customer2

```
etc.
```

The key is to make sure when you add graphics or images to your application from the AppGraphics directory (or the customer directory), make sure there is no directory path.

This solution has made it easier for me to continue developing the next upgrades and versions by moving the code and renaming some directories without having to edit my code because my directory path has changed.

This is lengthy, but I hope it helps!

~~~Tracy

Answer (score 0):

Within the IDE where you insert the icon file name, make sure you don't have a path (like "C:\graphics\myicon.ico") - only the name of the icon file.  Then make sure the icon files are somewhere in a folder within the PATH variable on your system.  When you build your application you can use a PBR file (a resource file) in the project for the application.  If you list all the graphic files used in the application in this resource file they will be included in the exe (and you won't have to distribute them separately).

Answer (score 0):

Matt is right on point with not using path names in your image references in the app.  Also correct that it is best to compile them into the app.
However, during development I like to separate my resources and DLLs into separate directories.  To do this without changing global env variables, you can include your directories in the PB "App Paths" registry section.

Depending on your PB Version...
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\pb125.exe"

There you will find a "PATH" value.  Just append your dev, resource, dll, directories to that path separated by ";" and PB will find them (requires restart).

I actually create reg files in the root of each app I'm working on to quickly register my paths.

Answer (score 0):

---

NOTE:  The same thing works with your final compiled application; but instead of using the PB section, there will be section created with the name of your executable.  Just do the same thing there - add paths where resources are separated from the EXE directory.